# Adding tooltip with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add tooltip to my tabular data(see pic) and i have loaded the tool tip function whenever the page is loaded . But i cant see any tooltip on tabular data .

[image]

here is code of html

```
<div class="row freightData">
    <div class="col-sm-2 tabularData" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
            <dt>Booking</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}</dd>

            <dt>Shipper</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.shipper}}</dd>

            <dt>Consignee</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.consignee}}</dd>

            <dt>VVD</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.vvd}}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

And this is the jQuery function I have loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('tooltip loading');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

My Tooltip function is also loading but I cant get pop over when I hover on tabular  data like shown in image. Please help me.

Comment: the tooltip value will come from title and it is empty

Answer (score 4):

#### Give your tool tip some value

```
<div class="row freightData">
    <div class="col-sm-2 tabularData" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Your Tool tip text here">
            <dt>Booking</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}</dd>

            <dt>Shipper</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.shipper}}</dd>

            <dt>Consignee</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.consignee}}</dd>

            <dt>VVD</dt>
            <dd>{{bookingData.vvd}}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70xps5sd/

Updated if you want to show value in columns as tooltip

```
<div class="row freightData">
        <div class="col-sm-2 tabularData">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>Booking</dt>
                <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}">{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}</dd>
    
                <dt>Shipper</dt>
                <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}">{{bookingData.shipper}}</dd>
    
                <dt>Consignee</dt>
                <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{bookingData.consignee}}">{{bookingData.consignee}}</dd>
    
                <dt>VVD</dt>
                <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="{{bookingData.vvd}}">{{bookingData.vvd}}</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
```

updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/70xps5sd/1/

Comment: hi , i tried adding this title attribute but i am trying to capture the value of <dd> tag as shown in image  but i am not sure how to do that .

Answer (score 0):

Simply just try below lines of code to show tooltip.

```
<div class="row freightData">
    <div class="col-sm-2 tabularData">
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Booking</dt>
            <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}">{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}</dd>

            <dt>Shipper</dt>
            <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="{{bookingData.bookingNumber}}">{{bookingData.shipper}}</dd>

            <dt>Consignee</dt>
            <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="{{bookingData.consignee}}">{{bookingData.consignee}}</dd>

            <dt>VVD</dt>
            <dd data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="{{bookingData.vvd}}">{{bookingData.vvd}}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not only title it should be like that data-original-title="Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

I have added a fiddler, might be what you are looking for...

```
"https://jsfiddle.net/3435x2fc/"
```

Please copy the link and check as i am having trouble in adding it to my comment